# How to check specific variable of all array objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array object with several variables. The objects are created by reading data from firebase.

```js
// Initialize cloud firestore database
let db = firebase.firestore();

//Create a class to store object data
class Data{
    constructor(ID,ame, type, location, address, category) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.type = type;
        this.location = location;
        this.address = address;
        this.category = category;
    }
}

//Get all documents in collection
db.collection("Basic_Data").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      Data_t = new Data(doc.ID,doc.data().type,doc.data().location,doc.data().address,doc.data().category);
      all_data.push(Data_t);
    });
});
```

I need to filter the objects based on certain conditions and if multiple filters are selected I need objects that satisfy all the conditions. I have no issues filtering that. After filtering, I try to consolidate values from the different filtering process. But some objects satisfy multiple conditions and are therefore included multiple times (not just twice). Thankfully, every object has a unique ID which I can use to filter the duplicates. But how do I check if an object with the unique ID is already present in the array?

```js
//Filter data by user selection
function dataFilter() {
  if ((document.getElementById("filter1-chkBox").checked) || (document.getElementById("filter2-chkBox").checked) || (document.getElementById("filter3-chkBox").checked) || (document.getElementById("filter4-chkBox").checked)) {
    if (document.getElementById("filter1-chkBox").checked) {
      temp_data_m = all_data.filter(function(info) {
        return info.condition1 == true;
      });
    }
    if (document.getElementById("filter2-chkBox").checked) {
      temp_data_w = all_data.filter(function(info) {
        return info.condition2 == true;
      });
    }
    if (document.getElementById("filter3-chkBox").checked) {
      temp_data_d = all_data.filter(function(info) {
        return info.condition3 == true;
      });
    }
    if (document.getElementById("filter4-chkBox").checked) {
      temp_data_h = all_data.filter(function(info) {
        return info.condition4 == true;
      });
    }
    
    //Consolidate all the filter results
    temp_data = temp_data_m;
    if (temp_data_m.length != 0) {
      temp_data_m = [];
    }
    if (temp_data_w.length != 0) {
      temp_data = temp_data.concat(temp_data_w);
      temp_data_w = [];
    }
    if (temp_data_d.length != 0) {
      temp_data = temp_data.concat(temp_data_d);
      temp_data_d = [];
    }
    if (temp_data_h.length != 0) {
      temp_data = temp_data.concat(temp_data_h);
      temp_data_h = [];
    }
    
    //Remove duplicates
    temp_data.forEach((info) => {
      if (!filtered_data.ID.includes(info.ID)) {
        filtered_data.push(info);
      }
    });
  } else {
    filtered_data = temp_data;
  }
}
```

I am trying to use forEach() and includes() to remove duplicates but I can't access the variable 'ID' from my array. How do I check the ID of all existing elements in the array?

Comment: I cannot follow any of your variables in the code. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example instead; with data?

Comment: I have added additional parts of the code but I'm afraid it will still not be reproducible since it needs firebase authentication. My issues are in the remove duplicates section.

Comment: Can you give us an example of `filtered_data` and `temp_data` from your console log?

Comment: If `filtered_data` is an array, how come you're trying to access `filtered_data.ID`? You need to target the element first, like `filtered_data[index].ID`

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. I can't specify the element to target. I want to search for ID on all the elements.

Comment: try this: `if(filtered_data.filter(data=>data.ID==info.ID)){filtered_data.push(info);}`

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: It runs without error but it doesn't remove the duplicates. It just concatenates the objects to the array.

Comment: Sorry, it would be the false value instead. Try this `if(!filtered_data.filter(data=>data.ID==info.ID)){filtered_data.push(info);}`. This will check if the `info.ID` is already in the `filtered_data` array or not

Comment: No. The statement is always false and the if condition is not executed. I get an empty array.

Comment: It's very difficult to check without data structure. Please include the data in your question

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

```js
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

Comment: I already use filter() to filter them. The problem is after filtering I need to remove the duplicates. And I don't know their IDs because they are auto-generated by firebase. So, I can only compare and look for matches.